# How to use ternary operator for multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, typescript

trying to add multiple conditions using ternary operator , values are coming false every time what is the issue with below code ? based on `isActive` flag value should set

index.js

```
   const _res: any = {}

_res.memberPreferences.channels.EM = (details.memberPreferences.channels[0].channelType === "EM" && details.memberPreferences.channels[0].isActive === "true") ? true : false;
_res.memberPreferences.channels.SMS = (details.memberPreferences.channels[0].channelType === "SMS" && details.memberPreferences.channels[0].isActive === "true") ? true : false
```

data

here is how the data is returned

```
{
    "details": {
        "memberPreferences": {
            "channels": [{
                    "channelType": "EM",
                    "isActive": "true"
                },
                {
                    "channelType": "SMS",
                    "isActive": "false"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have: `X ? true : false`, you can just use: `!!X` if you need an explicit boolean.  Also, you need to give us a Dataset to work with to test again.  ALSO, noticed that you never loop each channel, youre just checking the state of the first channel.

Answer (score 1):

You need no ternary, just the result of the comparison.

```js
const
    details = { memberPreferences: { channels: [{ channelType: "EM", isActive: "true" }, { channelType: "SMS", isActive: "false" }] } },
    _res = { memberPreferences: { channels: {} } },
    target = _res.memberPreferences.channels;

details.memberPreferences.channels.forEach(({ channelType, isActive }) => {
    target[channelType] = isActive === "true";
});

console.log(_res);
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP wants something like `target[k] = details.memberPreferences.channels.find(channel => channel.channelType === k).isActive`. Obviously there are more efficient ways to do it than an n^2 search like that, but it conveys the point within the context of your answer

Comment: Looks much better. I was going to write an answer if you didn't edit, but I think this covers what the OP is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need ternary operator here. The condition itself returns either `true` or `false`. Also, it's good to create separate variables for `details.memberPreferences.channels[0]` and `channel_zero.isActive == "true"` condition. And here there is no need to use `===` over `==`. So the `index.js` should look like this:

```
const _res: any = {};
const channel_zero: any = details.memberPreferences.channels[0];
const is_active: boolean = channel_zero.isActive == "true";

_res.memberPreferences.channels.EM = (channel_zero.channelType == "EM" && is_active);
_res.memberPreferences.channels.SMS = (channel_zero.channelType == "SMS" && is_active) ;
```

Comment: i really like the approach its simple don't we need a loop ?

Comment: @hussain You don't need a loop unless you want to iterate over the array of responses/channels/etc..

Comment: its only making first element true